# Wiener deconvolution in cpp giving back the same image

Tags: image-processing, dft, opencv, deconvolution, wiener-filter

I was trying to deblur a noisy image using wiener deconvolution.
I found [this](http://code-highlights.blogspot.com/2012/06/image-wiener-filter-for-white-noise.html) code which added noise to an image and removed it as well.
Modifying this code only i tried to implement the exact formula given on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution#Definition). But the output is same as input [image]

In the code i debugged a bit and found when i performed
 `magI=magI/x`
values in magI all became 1.
Can anyone please check if the calculation i have done are correct or not?
If so how do i prevent values in magI becoming 1

PS: I have included the full code in case anyone wants to learn and implement the code.
You can jump straight to wiener2 function as the error is in there.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat wiener2(Mat I, Mat image_spectrum, int noise_stddev);
Mat padd_image(Mat I);

Mat get_spectrum(Mat I);
Mat get_dft(Mat I);

Mat with_noise(Mat image, int stddev);
Mat rand_noise(Mat I, int stddev);

Mat createavg(Size imsize) ;
void shift(Mat magI);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int noise_stddev=20;
string input_filename="blur.png", output_filename="write.png";   // Have a blurred image here
cout << "noise standard deviation: " << noise_stddev << "\n";
cout << "input file: " << input_filename << "\n";

Mat I = imread(input_filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
if(I.data==NULL){
    cout << "Can't open file: " << input_filename << "\n";
    return 2;
}

Mat raw_sample = imread("blur.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
if(raw_sample.data==NULL){
    cout << "Can't open file: sample.bmp\n";
    return 3;
}

Mat padded = padd_image(I);
Mat noisy;

    noisy = with_noise(padded, noise_stddev);

Mat sample(padded.rows, padded.cols, CV_8U);
resize(raw_sample, sample, sample.size());    
Mat spectrum = get_spectrum(sample);    //to get signal spectrum of known image 
Mat enhanced = wiener2(noisy, spectrum, noise_stddev);
imshow("image 1", noisy);
imshow("image 2", enhanced);
waitKey();
}
Mat createavg(Size imsize) {


Mat kernel = Mat(5,5,CV_32FC1,Scalar(0.04));

int w = imsize.width-kernel.cols;
int h = imsize.height-kernel.rows;

int r = w/2;
int l = imsize.width-kernel.cols -r;

int b = h/2;
int t = imsize.height-kernel.rows -b;

Mat ret;
copyMakeBorder(kernel,ret,t,b,l,r,BORDER_CONSTANT,Scalar::all(0));

return ret;

}

//inputs are the blurry image with noise , the original image power spectra , and standard deviation of the noise introduced
Mat wiener2(Mat final_noise, Mat image_spectrum, int noise_stddev){
Mat padded = padd_image(final_noise);
Mat noise = rand_noise(padded, noise_stddev);
Mat noise_spectrum = get_spectrum(noise);

Scalar padded_mean = mean(padded);

Mat planes[2];
Mat complexI = get_dft(padded);
split(complexI, planes);    // planes[0] = Re(DFT(I), planes[1] = Im(DFT(I))

Mat factor = (noise_spectrum / image_spectrum); //calculates the signal to noise ratio
//-----------------compute the frequency domain multiplier



Mat mask = createavg(padded.size());            //creating the kernel which initally prduced the blurred image
shift(mask);// shifting the filter
Mat mplane[] = {Mat_<float>(mask), Mat::zeros(mask.size(), CV_32F)};
Mat kernelcomplex;
merge(mplane, 2, kernelcomplex); 

dft(kernelcomplex, kernelcomplex);  // computing dft of kernel

split(kernelcomplex, mplane);// splitting the dft of kernel to real and complex 
Mat x= mplane[0];
//cout<<x;

magnitude(mplane[0], mplane[1], mplane[0]);// planes[0] = magnitude
Mat magI = mplane[0];   
//cout<<magI;
multiply(magI,magI,magI);        //Computing |H(f)|^2
//cout<<factor;
factor+=magI;                   //adding to signal to noise ratio
//cout<<factor;
magI=magI/factor;   // calculating  (|H(f)|^2)/(|H(f)|^2 + S/N)         

//cout<<magI << " "<<x;
magI=magI/x;                //Dividing by the real value part of dft of kernel thus effectively multiplying by (1/H(f))
factor=magI;                
//cout<<magI;

//-------------------end


//multply both frequency domains and get final image in frequency domain
multiply(planes[0],factor,planes[0]);
multiply(planes[1],factor,planes[1]);


merge(planes, 2, complexI);
idft(complexI, complexI);
split(complexI, planes);
//  normalize(planes[0], planes[0], 0, 128, CV_MINMAX );
Scalar enhanced_mean = mean(planes[0]);
double norm_factor =  padded_mean.val[0] / enhanced_mean.val[0];
multiply(planes[0],norm_factor, planes[0]);
Mat normalized;
planes[0].convertTo(normalized, CV_8UC1);
return normalized;
}

Mat padd_image(Mat I){
Mat padded;
int m = getOptimalDFTSize( I.rows );
int n = getOptimalDFTSize( I.cols ); // on the border add zero pixels
copyMakeBorder(I, padded, 0, m - I.rows, 0, n - I.cols, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0));
return padded;
}

Mat get_spectrum(Mat I){
Mat complexI = get_dft(I);
Mat planes[2];
split(complexI, planes);                   // planes[0] = Re(DFT(I), planes[1] = Im(DFT(I))
magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);// planes[0] = magnitude
Mat magI = planes[0];
multiply(magI,magI,magI);
return magI;
}

Mat get_dft(Mat I){
Mat image;
I.convertTo(image, CV_32F);
Mat planes[] = {Mat_<float>(image), Mat::zeros(image.size(), CV_32F)};
Mat complexI;
merge(planes, 2, complexI);
dft(complexI, complexI);
return complexI;
}

Mat with_noise(Mat image, int stddev){
Mat noise(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8U);
rand_noise(image, stddev).convertTo(noise, CV_8U);
Mat noisy = image.clone();
noisy += noise;
return noisy;
}

Mat rand_noise(Mat I, int stddev){
Mat noise = Mat::zeros(I.rows, I.cols, CV_32F);
randn(noise,Scalar::all(0), Scalar::all(stddev));
return noise;
}
void shift(Mat magI) {

// crop if it has an odd number of rows or columns
magI = magI(Rect(0, 0, magI.cols & -2, magI.rows & -2));

int cx = magI.cols/2;
int cy = magI.rows/2;

Mat q0(magI, Rect(0, 0, cx, cy));   // Top-Left - Create a ROI per quadrant
Mat q1(magI, Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy));  // Top-Right
Mat q2(magI, Rect(0, cy, cx, cy));  // Bottom-Left
Mat q3(magI, Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy)); // Bottom-Right

Mat tmp;                            // swap quadrants (Top-Left with Bottom-Right)
q0.copyTo(tmp);
q3.copyTo(q0);
tmp.copyTo(q3);
q1.copyTo(tmp);                     // swap quadrant (Top-Right with Bottom-Left)
q2.copyTo(q1);
tmp.copyTo(q2);
}
```

[image: Input image]
Input image (noise is added by the code itself)

Comment: Do you expect people to debug your code?

Comment: @mathreadler No!!, i already pointed out where the bug is just want to know how I can prevent that bug.
Anyways i solved it posting the answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing

mat x=mplane[0]

resulted in a shallow copy of the matrix.

Doing a deep copy by cloning the matrix solved the problem.
It is a common mistake for beginners who are just into CPP and opencv.
Matrix pointers are just referred to same memory locations if we use the assigning operator